# how to set an image in wxStatusBar?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Is there any possible way that we can set a bitmap image in the wxStatusBar with the text?

Here I am talking about the Frame status bar.

Is there any function to set an image in the status bar?

If possible, then how can I achieve it?
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to [add controls to a wxStatusBar](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxStatusBar), doing the same with an [image](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_image.html) should work.

Comment: Also look at the statbar sample which shows how to do exactly this.